Get the Average of a varchar data with 'hh:mm:ss.mm' format in SQL Serve
I have a table in SQL Server where a field is called Total Conversation which is of type varchar and is in the format 'hh:mm:ss.mm'. This field shows the time that a call has lasted. What I want is to obtain the average of this time, whether in the month, day, etc. How can I do it in SQL Server? Any ideas? . Thanks in advance
This is a sample 00:00:03.092, there are also null values
Get the Average of a varchar data with 'hh:mm:ss.mm' format in SQL Serve

AVG() works on numeric types, not VARCHARs. Storing the data the way you have makes it very difficult to do what you want. If you had chosen instead to separate them into different columns (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds), it would be pretty easy. You're going to need to parse the VARCHAR to separate out those values, convert them all into a common numeric unit, which you can then AVG(), and then you can convert that AVG() back into the individual parts mathematically.
